# ShipStation issue with auto importing due to time issue?

Tags: php, date, opencart

Im new to the whole ecommerce scene, but im trying to get it where OpenCart will work with ShipStation to fill out shipment orders and handle the payments of them. However im getting this error in the error_log for the ShipStation extension module.

UPDATE:
Whats supposed to happen is when im on the app ShipStation and click Update from stores, it sends a request to this export.php script (thats shooting me the error).

```
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 20:25:03 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-07 22:25:08 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 15
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
2013-10-08 0:21:11 - PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/begumbou/public_html/shipstation/controller/export.php on line 22
```

line 15 states

```
$data['startdate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($starttime[0], $starttime[1], 0, $startdate[0], $startdate[1], $startdate[2]));
```

and line 22 states

```
$data['enddate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($endtime[0], $endtime[1], 0, $enddate[0], $enddate[1], $enddate[2]));
```

Heres all the code put together

```
    if (isset($this->request->get['start_date'])) {
        $start_date_time = explode(' ', $this->request->get['start_date']);
        $startdate = explode('/', $start_date_time[0]);
        $starttime = explode(':', $start_date_time[1]);
        $data['startdate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($starttime[0], $starttime[1], 0, $startdate[0], $startdate[1], $startdate[2]));
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['end_date'])) {
        $end_date_time = explode(' ', $this->request->get['end_date']);
        $enddate = explode('/', $end_date_time[0]);
        $endtime = explode(':', $end_date_time[1]);
        $data['enddate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($endtime[0], $endtime[1], 0, $enddate[0], $enddate[1], $enddate[2]));
```

UPDATE ERROR_LOG

```
[08-Oct-2013 17:33:39 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => 01%3a08
)

[08-Oct-2013 17:33:39 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => 17%3a33
)
```

this was on the raw_error_logs, it matches the array given above.

```
162.209.46.39 - - [08/Oct/2013:13:33:39 -0400] "GET /shipstation/index.php?action=export&start_date=10%2f08%2f2013+01%3a08&end_date=10%2f08%2f2013+17%3a33&page=1&SS-UserName=R4ND0ML3TT3RSANDNUB3RS1T00K0UT&SS-Password=R4ND0ML3TT3RSANDNUB3RS1T00K0UT HTTP/1.1" 302 448 "-" "ShipStation"
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_dump($starttime);` and `var_dump($endtime`)? You are using same value for hour and month, minute and day, that has to be wrong. Start developing with `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);`.

Comment: @Glavić `You are using same value for hour and month, minute and day` - I thought the exact same thing as You, but the truth is he is using `$startdate` and `$starttime` and `$enddate` and `$endtime` variables...

Comment: @shadyyx: lol, missed that ;) Still, when he dumps this variables, he/we will find problem ;)

Comment: So just add the line `var_dump($starttime);` and $endtime to get those?, little new to PHP too. More of an iOS / HTML/ jQuery and Android guy ;)

Comment: After seeing a downvote i recognized my question is a little vague and i didnt even explain what i was doing to get this error. Ive updated my answer, hopefully that downvote goes away.

Comment: updated with those logs, im dumb founded still...

Answer (score 1):

With GET link you have given `GET /shipstation/index.php?action=export&start_date=10%2f08%2f2013+01%3a08&...`, notices should not happen.

Notices come when `start_date` or `end_date` are in different format than you expect.

Replace your code:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['start_date'])) { ... }
if (isset($this->request->get['end_date'])) { ... }
```

with:

```
foreach (array('start_date', 'end_date') as $field) {
    if (!isset($this->request->get[$field])) continue;
    $date = $this->request->get[$field];
    try {
        $dt = new DateTime($date);
        $data[str_replace('_', '', $field)] = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit("ERROR: Field '{$field}' has invalid datetime format = '{$date}' ({$e->getMessage()})");
    }
}
```

and see if error happens.